# Consequences of SendTimeOut at client side

Tags: c#, wcf

There's a requirement for the application to know about the service unavailability as soon as possible. The client uses the default sendTimeOut and ReceiveTimeOut. Now i want to reduce the SendTimeOut to 10 seconds so that within 10-12 seconds my UI will come to know abt the Service unavailability and react accordingly.

Q.1 Am i on the right track on reducing the service unavailability time by reducing the SendTimeOut at client config?

Q.2 What are the consequences of this?

Q.3 Any better approach?

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of unavailability do you want to detect?

1. The server has crashed?
2. The service has crashed?
3. The service is waiting for some internal resource to perform work?
4. The hosting application is out of handling threads?
5. Something else?

Consider that 1, 2 and 4 can will detected almost immediately, regardless of timeout. 
In general, you should not infer unavailability based only on time. You need to take into account other properties such as message size and transmission latency.

Moreover, what binding are you using? If you are using MSMQ binding, there is absolutely no way to know whether the service is available according to request-response patterns.